# Problem with the analytical study of transient processes in nonlinear systems with linear dynamic links

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, nonlinear, control-systems, differential-geometry

I ask for advice and help.

I am having difficulties of this nature. There is a nonlinear system of the following type:

[image]

I need to analyze analytically the transient process in such a system. **The analytical study of the transient process is understood as the solution $x(t)$ of the differential equation for such system and its analysis, i.e.:**

*1. Estimation of the time of the transient process by analyzing the properties of the solution components.*

*2. Assessment of the presence / absence of oscillatory components.*

*3. Estimation of the amplitude of the oscillatory components.*

**The situation is complicated by the following circumstances:**

*1. The presence of linear dynamic links in the system, which implies the use of LTI techniques. At the same time, the presence of a quadratic nonlinear link makes this impossible.*

*2. The presence of a nonlinear quadratic link forces us to consider the option of drawing up the corresponding differential equation in the system. At the same time, the presence of linear dynamic links in the system determines the presence of convolution operators in the differential equation, which turns the differential equation into an integro-differential equation with a complex structure, the methods for solving which in general form do not exist.*

**Problem:**

*It is necessary to choose the path of analytical calculation of transient processes in a nonlinear system with linear dynamic links.*

**Probably solution:**

**Write the entire system as a system of ode and use the tools of Mathematica to analyze nonlinear state-space or some other method.**

With this question I contacted the Math Stack Exchange and the Engineering Stack Exchange. I received no substantive answer.

I would be glad to any advice and help from specialists, which path and method to choose. *Numerical methods are not considered.* I need to know the analytical description of the transient process to analyze it.

**Remark:** The system of differential equations for such a system turns out to be insoluble. Therefore, approximate methods can be used.

**Integro-Differential equation of system:**

If each linear link is taken as a model in the state space, then its solution is known (if we assume that the initial state for each of them = 0):

$out(t) = \int_0^t B u(\tau ) e^{A (t-\tau )} \, d\tau$

If I am not mistaken anywhere, the integro-differential equation will look like this.

$\frac{dx}{dt} = \int_0^t B_2 (-\left(\int_0^t B_1 x(\tau ) e^{A_1 (t-\tau )} \, d\tau \right){}^2) e^{A_2 (t-\tau )} \, d\tau + D_2
   (-\left(\int_0^t B_1 x(\tau ) e^{A_1 (t-\tau )} \, d\tau \right){}^2)$

Comment: This does not look a question about the software mathematica. Are you on the correct site?  If you do want to investigate this problem in mathematica then you need to start by giving you differential equation. It looks like you are working with Laplace variables. Laplace will only work for linear systems. We need to see the differential equation to get started.

Comment: I've added details, let's try to figure it out.

Comment: How do you expect to do a numerical analysis without any explicit values?

Comment: It doesn't matter now. The main thing is to develop a technology for numerical analysis that will answer the questions I have posed. Better yet, find an analytical solution.

Comment: You have already noticed that there are two contradictory moments in the circuit that do not allow directly applying either the Laplace transform (due to nonlinear elements), or directly solving the differential equation (due to the complexity of its structure and nonlinearity). I'm at a crossroads, and I don't know which way to go.

Comment: Which is the nonlinearity that you see? Have you looked at TransferFunctionModel or InverseLaplaceTransfermation ? What is your attempt with MMA to solve this? Generally we prefer to answer, actual questions and solve with solutions from your attempt...at the moment it seems like you don‘t know what you‘re looking at, and you‘re asking for someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: I am answering your question. The nonlinearity here is the block with $-u^2$. In addition, the block may contain $exp(-u^2), \frac{1}{u^2+1}, sech(u)^2$. How can the Laplace transform help here? I do not understand. And there are no results due to the fact that I tried to solve the ODE directly, but I failed.

Comment: @morbo, can you tell me how to investigate transients in these types of systems? Maybe there are approximate or advanced methods?

Comment: I gave you an answer...Is $s$ supposed to represent frequency? You have given a block diagram for a system with a single input and -single output with -u^2 as a simple gain in positive feedback....if your system is *not* a block diagram of a system in frequency spectrum, then you need to change your question to something more clear, at the moment, your system is solvable within seconds with the commands I gave you, if you want a general mathematics answer with an unknown general ODE of multiple inputs in time spectrum you need should ask over at maths.SE

Comment: @morbo, "...at the moment, your system is solvable within seconds with the commands I gave you". Could you please demonstrate how you did it using these commands? $U$ is not gain, that block is function $f(u)$ from input signal, that square the input!

Comment: @morbo, if you can suggest something (approximate ways or advanced methods), give me a hint, please. I'm stumped.